# Dependency injection on class with only static methods?

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have a set of API classes which contain only static methods and a single private constructor so they cannot be instantiated. However, I would like a third party developer to be able to modify the behaviour of the API's to suit their needs.

---

This is the solution I have so far (dependency injection via static setter method). This is the public API class that the developer would use. As you can see, it has a dependency on `StaticApiImpl`.

```
public class StaticApi {
    private static StaticApiImpl impl = new StaticApiImpl();

    private StaticApi() {}

    public static void setImpl(StaticApiImpl impl) {
        StaticApi.impl = impl;
    }

    public static void doThing() {
        impl.doThing();
    }
}
```

This is the default API implementation as coded myself.

```
public class StaticApiImpl {
    public void doThing() {
        System.out.println("Do thing the default way.");
    }
}
```

This is a hypothetical extended version of the default implementation that a third party might write:

```
public class MyCustomStaticApiImpl extends StaticApiImpl {
    @Override
    public void doThing() {
        System.out.println("Do thing differently.");
    }
}
```

The developer would then simply inject their dependency via the setter method upon initialisation of their plugin:

```
public void onLoad() throws Exception {
    StaticApi.setImpl(new MyCustomStaticApiImpl());
}
```

My question is: is this the correct way of doing it? Is there perhaps some design pattern dedicated to cases such as this that I have not heard of?

Comment: I would remove the StaticApi class completely, and let the developer inject an instance of StaticApiImpl or of a subclass.

Comment: No, there's not correct way doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are setting up here is a factory pattern with the ability for clients to configure which implementation the factory returns. That is fine, but there are a couple of things that you need to do differently.

1. Rename `StaticApi` to `StaticApiFactory`. This will make its role more clear and avoid a naming conflict with the next parts.
2. Remove the `public static void doSomething()` method. There's no need to redefine all of your API methods as static methods. Since that is a factory class, all you need instead is a method to get the current implementation, e.g. a `public static StaticApi getInstance()` method that returns the implementation that has been set via `setImpl()`.
3. Create an interface `StaticApi` that defines the contract of the APIs behavior. The factory class should then allow the clients to `setImpl(StaticApi)`.
4. Now anyone that needs to use the StaticApi can get a reference via `StaticApiFactory.getInstance()`.

Comment: While I understand the reasoning behind this answer, it does make it more verbose for callers. Contrast `StaticApi.doSomething()` vs. `StaticApiFactory.getInstance().doSomething()`

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for your 3rd party developer will be using the `Proxy` pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern

Setting the implementation object as instance is not great solution.